# problem cgi <form action with python on raspberry

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, cgi, action

I am trying to use cgi to navigate from a python3 program and php program ( joomla 3.86 on raspberry )
the following simple program is ok and an html page opens when I launch it from localweb.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import cgi

print("Content-type: text/html\n\r\n")
print()

print("essai print")"""
```

but when I try to launch the following  formtest.py program ( ultimately I want to do it with a php program )
#!/usr/bin/python3

```
import cgi

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<html>")
print("<FORM ACTION="192.168.4.1/cgi-bin/echo.py" METHOD="POST">")
print("<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="send" VALUE="Exécuter le script"></FORM>")
print("</html>")
```

where echo.py is also simple and works alone when launched from local site ( all programs are placed in www/cgi-bin/ )

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


import cgi

print("Content-type: text/html\n\r\n")
print()

print("essai print")
```

I get the following error ( seen from etc/apache2/error log ) :

```
Sat Jul 11 11:45:48.291525 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 17883] [client 192.168.4.1:49084] AH01215:   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/formtest.py", line 8: /var/www/cgi-bin/formtest.py
[Sat Jul 11 11:45:48.291773 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 17883] [client 192.168.4.1:49084] AH01215:     print("<form action="echo.php" method="POST">"): /var/www/cgi-bin/formtest.py
[Sat Jul 11 11:45:48.291830 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 17883] [client 192.168.4.1:49084] AH01215:                             ^: /var/www/cgi-bin/formtest.py
[Sat Jul 11 11:45:48.291882 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 17883] [client 192.168.4.1:49084] AH01215: SyntaxError: invalid syntax: /var/www/cgi-bin/formtest.py
[Sat Jul 11 11:45:48.317873 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 17883] [client 192.168.4.1:49084] End of script output before headers: formtest.py
```

I tried all combinations with and without html code , different adresses for echo.py ( cgi-bin/formtest.py , 192.168.4.1/cgi-bin/ etc
I removed either the form action line or the input line and got the same nasty error

Strange because I saw at least 2 sites showing this king of form action link with python3 and cgi pointing to a .py program .
Next question is , if you can solve my problem , can I do it with a PHP program ?

thanks very much to get interested with my problem

Bernard

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : just put the whole html code under a same print using """

```
#!/usr/bin/python3


print("Content-type: text/html")
print("""
<FORM ACTION="echo.php" METHOD="post">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="send" VALUE="Action">
</FORM>
""")
```

and the program pointing to can be .py or .php

hope this can help someone one day

Bernard